# Bone moves other parts that i dont want to be moved

Tags: bones

I made a basic rig and inside the rig which is a monkey as you can see and i made bones with automatic weights on it

my problem here is that everytime i move my upper arm bone in posing the ear moves with it

[image: before moving the bone]

[image: after moving the bone]

Now im not sure how to fix it since i cant find yt videos about the problem, but here is the thing that i tried so far.

Remake Amature

I want it to not move with the arm but only the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the ear vertices in *Edit* mode and *Remove from All Groups*:

[image]

Then assign to the correct vertex group (the one that has the name of the head bone):

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!!!